# Who is Mr Escher?

Tags: character, continuum

In Continuum S0E10, Agent Gardiner is introduced and is very suspicious of Kiera, and begins performing a variety of background checks on her.

Just before the major explosion near the end of the episode, he gets a call from 'his superior' who advises him that a Mr Escher from Section Six has informed his agency to cooperate fully with Kiera.

At the end of the episode, it is clarified that Mr Escher is neither Kellog or Alec.

Who is Mr Escher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [continuum.wikia.com](http://continuum.wikia.com/wiki/Escher) -

> Mr. Escher is the head of Piron Corporation, one of the top corporations in the future. He traveled back in time to ensure that the future stays on track. He also seems to be planting his roots earlier in time.
>
> First mentioned in [End
> times](http://continuum.wikia.com/wiki/End_Time), [Jason](http://continuum.wikia.com/wiki/Jason) says Mr. Escher is a privateer, or a freelancer.
> A Mr. Escher then vouches for [Kiera](http://continuum.wikia.com/wiki/Kiera)'s [Section Six](http://continuum.wikia.com/wiki/Section_Six) cover.

Mr Escher's first appearance on screen in the show is in the episode "Second Truths". He is the head of Piron Corporation, which turns out to be one of the top corporations in 2077. He travelled back in time to ensure that the actions of Liber8 to not change the course of the future.